# How can I remove the spacing above a block element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a website and I have come across a problem that I cannot seem to fix. The layout of my page is completely designed by HTML DIVs and certain elements are nested in relative position to their parent DIV. I am trying to position a banner-wrap DIV underneath the DIV which holds my navigation menu without having any space between it, but I cannot figure out how to remove the space.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <body class='landing-page wsite-theme-light'>
        <div id="nav-mast">
            <div class="container">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td id="logo">{logo}</td>
                    <td id="nav">{menu}</td>
                    </tr>
            </table><!-- end navigation table -->
        </div><!-- end nav bar contanier -->
    </div><!-- end navigation mast -->
    <div id="landing-wrap">
        <div class="container">     
        <div id="banner">
            <div class="wsite-header"></div>
        </div><!-- end banner -->
            <div id="banner-social-screen">
                <h3>Contact</h3>
                {social}
        </div><!-- end banner social screen -->
        <div id="banner-screen">
            <div class="banner-screen-inner">
                <div class="banner-screen-content">
                    <h2>{headline:text global="false"}</h2>
                    <p>{headline-paragraph:text global="false"}</p>
                    <div id="landing-button">{action:button global="false"}</div>
                </div><!-- end banner screen content -->
            </div><!-- end inner banner screen -->
        </div><!-- end banner screen -->
        </div><!-- end landing container -->
    </div><!-- end landing wrap -->
```

The navigation bar is the **nav-mast** div and the space is being created between the **nav-mast** DIV and the **landing-wrap** DIV. The **landing-wrap** DIV holds a header image with two semi-transparent elements which are held in the **banner-screen** and **banner-screen-social** DIVs. The **banner-screen-social** DIV has an *h3 text element* and the social icons for my website. The **banner-screen** DIV has an *h2 text element* that holds my landing page headline and a *p text element* that holds the paragraph-headline. I want both the **banner-screen-social** and **banner-screen** elements to appear on top of the image (as they do), but my issue is that there is now a spacing between the bottom of the **nav-mast** element and the top of the **landing-wrap** element.

This is my current CSS which [results in a space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5jTt.png) (image in link):

```
.landing-page #banner-screen {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.70);
}

.landing-page #landing-wrap {
    background-image: url(banner-tall.jpg);
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow:    -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
box-shadow:         -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
}

.landing-page .banner-screen-content h2 {
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Sansation', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.landing-page .banner-screen-content p {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 14px;
    left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.landing-page #banner-social-screen {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.70);
}

.landing-page #banner-social-screen h3 {
top: 5px;
    left: 3px;
    font-family: 'Sansation', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

This is what my CSS was [before the space occurred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiIdy.png) (image in link):

```
.landing-page #banner-screen {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.70);
}

.landing-page #landing-wrap {
    background-image: url(banner-tall.jpg);
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
-moz-box-shadow:    -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
box-shadow:         -7px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.7);
}

.landing-page .banner-screen-content h2 {
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-family: 'Sansation', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.landing-page .banner-screen-content p {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 0px;
    line-height: 14px;
    left: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: normal;
}

.landing-page #banner-social-screen {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background: rgba(176, 176, 176, 0.70);
    position: relative;
}

.landing-page #banner-social-screen h3 {
top: 5px;
    left: 3px;
    font-family: 'Sansation', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

The issue with that being that I could not properly position the banner-social-screen element when it was displayed as an inline-block.

Is there any way to remove the space between the nav-mast and landing-wrap elements without removing the banner-screen and banner-screen-social blocks from my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the position: absolute; attribute in CSS. You would mostlikely need to use this for both the nav-mast and landing-wrap. If the divs still should the unwanted gap try top:0px;. If the gap is still present then try using a negative top:-15px;. You may be able to do this without the position attribute but I tend to use it more often than not.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I only had to position the landing-wrap with absolute for it to work; doing both landing-wrap and nav-mast made the entire navigation bar disappear. The space is gone and my elements are aligned how I want them to be. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Get some good reading material and you will be a pro in no time!. Take care.